# Converting a curl into guzzle code in php

Tags: php, curl, guzzle, onesignal

I have a curl code like this which I am trying to convert into `guzzle` like so

```
$response = $client->post(self::$url, [
        'query' => array(
            'app_id' => "app-id",
            'included_segments' => array('All'),
            'contents' => $content,
            'headings' => $headings) ],
              ['headers' => [
                      'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                      'Authorization' => 'Basic api key'
              ]
        ]);
```

But when I try to run this I get this error

```
...` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:\n{\"errors\":[\"Please include a case-sensitive header of Authorization: Basic <YOUR-REST-API-KEY-HERE> with a valid REST AP (truncated...)
```

CURL

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8','Authorization: Basic api key'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
```

Comment: What the curl code looks like?

Comment: i have added the curl code @Veve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Guzzle is this? Because the [latest](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html) is different.

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$req = $client->request('POST', self::$url, [
    'json' => ['app_id' => '...', 'foo' => 'bar'],
    'headers' => ['Authorization' => 'Basic api key']
]);
$res = $client->getBody()->getContents();
```

I'm pretty sure that `'json'` adds automatically the specific header, otherwise transform `'json'` in `'form_params'` and add the header (`content-type`).

Comment: this says it requires a `Magic request methods require a URI and optional options array` @Grork

Comment: Try with `new GuzzleHttp\Client([]);` but it's weird

Comment: it worked I was passing the parameters wrongly. Thanks for the help.